# Display end date in textbox with User Selected Start Date + 1 year using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For Example is a user selects 27/01/2016, the 'End Date' Text Box will display 27/01/2017 which will be un-editable. Preferably without using JQueryDate function

Comment: How are they selecting it? Through a `select` dropdown? Or is it a text `input`? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Through a text input using date as the input type. I would put some code up if I knew any but I unfortunately don't know any code for tit

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.slice()` , set `disabled` attribute at `input type="date"` element that is `.nextElementSibling` of first `input type="date"` element

---

Edit, Updated

Added `new Date()`, `.toJSON()` to handle leap years, as pointed out by @itachi

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.onchange = function(e) {
  var val = this.value;
  // add `1` to first four characters of `this.value` : `yyyy` 
  this.nextElementSibling.value = new Date(1 + +val.slice(0, 4) 
                                  + val.slice(4)).toJSON().slice(0, 10)
}
```

```html
<input type="date" /><input type="date" disabled>
```

Comment: Leap years are not processed correctly. Check for 2016-02-29.

Answer (score 0):

A solution, would be to have two date inputs.

The first one would be used by user to select date. This one disapears once the user select a date.

The second one would be invisble and `readonly`. Once the user has selected a date, this one is initiated with the Date + 1y and displayed.

You can use simple javascript to add + 1, see [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) javascript object

Answer (score 0):

As Dionys said, have a `readonly` input field for your output, something like:

```
<p>
  <input type="text" id="date" />
</p>
<p>
  <input type="text" id="output" readonly="readonly" />
</p>
```

Then, well assuming the date is being selected in that format, which is a bad jump to make but the only one I can at this time, a little `split()` and `join()` action:

```
var date = document.getElementById('date');

date.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var val = date.value, y = '', parts = [];
    if(val) {
        parts = val.split('/');
        y = parts.length - 1;
        parts[y] = parseInt(parts[y], 10) + 1;
        document.getElementById('output').value = parts.join('/');
    }
}, false);
```

Give or take, that should run just fine as long as the date is being presented with the year last. If you post a link to your code or update your question, I can narrow this down to be more accurate.

**[Fiddles](https://jsfiddle.net/30myeus4/1/)**

Comment: It will give a false result for leap years.

Comment: It was just a start, here's the code needed for that, use as need: `if(m == 2 && ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0)) { // leap year`

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on your input type. Is it a pure `Date` object from JavaScript or just a simple `String` formatted as `dd/MM/yyyy`?

### Date input

It is pretty easy - the only thing to do is to increment a year and then convert the date to your format.

```
var d = new Date(); // It's for presentation. You already have it from your input.
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear()+1);
var str = [d.getDate(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
```

### String input

It is a little modified example from the above. You have to parse your string firstly, and how will you do it, depends on your date format. I will assume here, that this is `dd/MM/yyyy`.

```
var s = '28/01/2016';
var chunks = s.split('/');

d = new Date(chunks[2], chunks[1]-1, chunks[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);

d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear()+1);
var str = [d.getDate(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
```